# How to setup Meteor Raix Push Package for Push Notifications

Tags: cordova, meteor, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to use this [Push](https://github.com/raix/push/) Meteor package for Android and Chrome push notification. I followed the [basic instructions](https://github.com/raix/push/blob/master/docs/BASIC.md) and added the GCM credentials to config.push.json file in the root directory.

I tried sending a push notification with the command below for the browser, Android simulator, and Android phone.

```
  Push.send({
    from: 'Test',
    title: 'Hello',
    text: 'World',
    count: 12,
    query: {
      userId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'
    }
  });
```

When I enter the command in the browser console I get the following error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
 notifications.js:40
```

This seems to be due to the fact that there isn't a logged in user.

On the Meteor Shell, I get a token back, but both cases a push notification is not sent.

If you have any ideas why the push notification is not sent, please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I am sending push notifications successfully to android phone...trying sending push notifications to everyone, that means omit userId

`Push.send({
    from: 'Test',
    title: 'Hello',
    text: 'World',
    count: 12,
    query: {
    }
  });`

After it you can log in on your app and try to send notifications only to logged in user. You have to copy the user id from mongodb and put it to into query, e.g.

```
query: {

userId: 'xfaafsdlfhjeorhj239n'

```
}
```

```

If you are not using meteor's insecure package add

`Push.allow({
        send: function(userId, notification) {
            return true; // Allow all users to send
        }
    });`